# "ErrorUtils caught an error" - Chrome console error with any Wordpress Facebook plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to use a Facebook likebox plugin on a staging site and I have tried some different plugins. Independently from plugin installed I receive the same error in Chrome console:

*ErrorUtils caught an error: "Cannot listen to an undefined element. TAAL[2]". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.*

I think the problem is generated directly from Facebook plugin inclusion. Unfortunately the url https://fburl.com/debugjs isn't working.

This issue doesn't apparently create any problem to the site, but I would like to have a site without any error in console.

Tee site is http://millennium.alecss.it/

Let me know if you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I would like to contact some Facebook developer, but it is not quite easy.

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: I am looking for this solution to.

Comment: same for me... i got this error suddenly, i'm not sure if this also could be a chrome error, because i think started to appear when i updated chrome recently

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1337180213092053

Answer (score 1):

This is the bug, when upgrade jQuery since 1.8.
Look in your code and replace to on('load')

```
$(window).load(
function(){
//your code
});
```

To

```
$(window).on('load', 
function(){ 
//your code
});
```